# Display a popup a couple of times

Tags: javascript, popup

I've created a popup that triggers when the user scrolls to a certain part of the page:

```
  if(localStorage.getItem('popState') != 'shown'){
    var modalwaypoint = $('#learning').waypoint({
      handler: function(direction) {
        if (direction == 'down') {
          $('#modalwaypoint').foundation('open');
          localStorage.setItem('popState','shown')
        }
        this.destroy()
      },
      offset: '10%'
    });
  }
```

I think when someone looks at the page they may delete the pop-up first time, but on coming back to the page and seeing the pop-up again they may be more tempted to click the CTA.

I'd like to keep the localStorage method, but allow the popup box to show again after x amount of hours or days, and then not show after that.  I'm fairly new to javascript, so still trying to get my head around it, can anyone help?

Many Thanks

snarf1974

Answer (score 1):

Using `localStorage` why not set something like the following at the same time you store `popState`?

```
localStorage.setItem('popupLastShown', new Date().getTime());
```

Then you can

- Retrieve the last time the popup was shown
- Decide if it should be shown again
- If you show it, store the new time

Here is the example you asked for in your comment. Keep in mind it's simple and that I am not familiar with the `waypoint` or `foundation` methods that you are using.

```
    function showPopup() {
        var lastShown = localStorage.getItem('popupLastShown'),
            now = new Date().getTime();

        if(localStorage.getItem('popState') !== 'shown') {
            return true;
        }

        if((now - lastShow) >= 86400000 /* 1 day in milliseconds */) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    if(showPopup()){
        var modalwaypoint = $('#learning').waypoint({
            handler: function(direction) {
                if (direction == 'down') {
                    $('#modalwaypoint').foundation('open');
                    localStorage.setItem('popState','shown');
                    localStorage.setItem('popupLastShown', new Date().getTime());
                }

                this.destroy();
            },

            offset: '10%'
        });
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much for this answer.  Could you possibly show me how to include this into my code.  As I mentioned, I am not that confident in javascript at the moment, but hope to get up to speed soon.

Comment: Do you have to set an item by providing it two parameters? the first being the key, the second being the value?

Comment: Yes you have to provide two parameters. First one is the item. Second one is the value to set. See [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) docs.

Comment: Hey @gforce301, thanks for the example. I still can't get it to work, but am trying to figure it all out.  This is the waypoints I'm using to trigger the popup when the page reaches an id on the page: http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

Comment: @snarf1974 I would need you to show me actual code as an example at this point. Edit your question and add more code that shows the problem. The code I have in my answer is more or less a drop in replacement of the code that you have in your question.

Comment: Sorry for this late reply.  In the end we decided to just display the popup once.  Thank you so much for all your help.